# Which versions of pandas Altair supports?

Tags: altair

I want to know the supported versions of pandas to update pandas 0.x to 1.x in my code, which also uses altair.

There is no version defined in requirements.txt.

Which versions of pandas Altair supports? Is it OK to update it to 1.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only official recommendation is to use pandas [version 0.18 or newer](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/8a8642b2e7eeee3b914850a8f7aacd53335302d9/requirements.txt#L5), but no official word on a maximum compatible version. That said, I've personally been using Altair with pandas 1.X for over a year and have not seen any issues.